# ajax realtime refresh of values of word occurences using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried searching for solutions but I could not handle it properly. Also, I want it to display using AJAX. So every time I type a word, it will appear below the textbox with a counter beside it. 
My current code is this:

The output should be like this:
with the input of "the quick brown fox"

```
brown -- 1 
fox -- 2 
quick -- 1 
the -- 1
```

but my current output is:

```
brown -- 1 
fox -- 1 
fox -- 2 
quick -- 1 
the -- 1 
//the fox displays twice.
```

My index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Working with Javascript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--textbox-->
        <input type="text" name="input" id="textInput" autofocus/>
        <!--where the answer will appear-->
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //get the content of the textbox
        var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
        //transform it into jQuery
        var jTextInput = $("#textInput");
        var divSelector = document.getElementById("content");
        //the AJAX function
        textInput.onkeyup = function () {
            console.log($("#textInput").val());
            $.ajax({
                "method": "POST", //to specify what type of METHOD to 
REQUEST in the SERVER (GET or POST)
                "url": "assignment2.php", // where to send the request
                "dataType": "JSON", // datatype of the request
                "data": {
                    "text": $("#textInput").val() //DATA values that you'll 
send
                }, 
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#content").html(res.reversedString);
                }
            });
        };
    </script>    
</html>
```

and my assignment2.php

```
<?php
/*
//note: if you delete everything and left the commented code below, the text 
displays as you type in the textbox.
//$vari = array("reversedString" => $_POST['text']);
//echo json_encode($vari);
*/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//get the content of textbox
$vari = array("reversedString" => $_POST['text']);
$var = $vari;
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

//make it an array 
$words = explode(' ', $var);
//sort by a-z
sort($words);
$result = array_combine($words, array_fill(0, count($words), 0));
//total number of words
$len = count($words);
//the array for the number of occurences
$totals = array();

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $result[$word] ++;
    array_push($totals, $result[$word]);
}
//the array for the words and number of occurences
$finalarray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    array_push($words[$i] . " -- " . $totals[$i] . " <br>");
}
//make the array back to sentence
$regularexpression = implode(" ", $finalarray);

$last = array("reversedString" => $regularexpression);
echo json_encode($last);
```

I'll answer any blurry information I have. This is an assignment of mine. Please help and thankyou for patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if statement inside your for each loop

You check if it's there, using in_array, before pushing.

```
foreach($words as $word){if(!in_array($word, $liste, true)){
    array_push($liste, $word);
}}
```